# c# lock return/continue/break

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

If I have the following code:

```
lock(SyncRoot){ return value; }
```

Will the SyncRoot be unlocked before the return statement?

I tried walking through the code in VS2005, but it doesn't actually show one way or another.  It looks like it DOES unlock it, but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does unlock no matter how you exit the block (i.e. return, break, throw, etc).

See [MSDN - lock statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) for more details:

> The lock keyword ensures that one thread does not enter a critical section of code while another thread is in the critical section.
>   ...
>   The lock keyword calls Enter at the start of the block and Exit at the
>   end of the block.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can think of it expanding to something like this:

```
Monitor.Enter(obj);
try {
    var result = value;
}
finally {
    Monitor.Exit(obj);
}
return result;
```

If you look at the generated IL, it is something like that. If `value` were an expression though, it would be evaluated before releasing the lock. The return is executed after releasing the lock.

The finally block is called in any case, so yes, the lock is released.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it calculates value (if value were an expression this may be important), then unlocks and returns. A lock() is always unlocked automatically when you exit its scope, no matter how you do it.

Answer (score 2):

It will unlock after the block is executed.

This syntax is similar to `using`, btw. The only reason the `lock` is outside of the block is to show that there is a lock at start, unlock at end functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `lock` actually uses `Monitor.Enter`/`Monitor.Exit` in the background. The expanded version of your code is in fact this

```
Monitor.Enter (SyncRoot);
try
{
    return value;
}
finally { Monitor.Exit (SyncRoot); }
```

The `finally` block is guaranteed to be executed before the method actually returns, so the lock is released.

Answer (score 2):

If you have something like `
            int i = 0;
            object o = new object();

```
        while (i < 100)
        {
            lock (o)
            {
                if (i == 10)
                    continue;
            }

            ++i;
        }`
```

this will result in a deadlock because 
it will wait forever to acquire the 
lock saved from the previous execution 
context before continue

Answer (score 0):

No, the lock is released only **after** the return statement.